# Jasper Server...where is the dashboard?

Tags: jasperserver

I have not used JasperReports in a number of years.  It has changed  :-)  I've decided that the Community version of Jasper Server is what I need.  The install (Postgres and Tomcat defaults) went smoothly and was happy when poking around the result.  However, I cannot get my MySQL datasource to test correctly...even though I'm logged in as an admin user and the connection (all at localhost) works fine in JasperStudio.  To make matters worse, I want to use the dashboard tool.  All the tutorials show what looks like a dash for the tool that includes a big Dashboard icon...but I don't know how to see that page.  For me, it defaults to a page with a folder listing on the left and repository display in the main frame.  Where is the tool's dashboard?  I don't even see the "create" tab across the top frame...all I see is: Library, View, Manage...

Did I miss something in the setup?  I followed the directions that came with the 7.x install without any red flags...

Answer (score 0):

Jasper Servevr Community edition does not supports features like adhoc reporting, dashboards, visualize.js etc.. If you are looking for Dashboard feature either you have to use Professional or Enterprise.